# Why ESLint prefer-const wants object or array defined as const?

Tags: constants, eslint

Take this lines as examples:

```
let c=[]
c[0]=23
```

and these:

```
let creationDate = new Date(date)
creationDate.setDate(creationDate.getDate() + daysTTL);
```

Both let statements will raise ESLint ERROR

```
Identifier .... is never reassigned; use 'const' instead of 'let'.
```

Is there a better way to instruct ESLint that I'm actually changing the values, or that this rules doesn't apply/fit well with structured data?

Or should I switch to const ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

actually the issue raised be ESLint is due to small difference, whereby `const` is used for variables that are never reassigned using the `=` while `let` for variables that will be surely be reassigned using `=`.

let me explain using your two examples,
the first example the variable `c` was not reassigned, just the value of the its element has been changed or assigned so the reassignment was not performed on `c` but on its element `c[0]`

regarding the second example, you are changing the value of a property of an object but you are not reassigning that object to another or to new.

whether to use `const` or `let` it depends on whether you will ever reassign using `=`.

hope this was helpful

Comment: Then... Maybe there's a misconception from my side of the meaning of const...  The only constant I see here is the pointer to memory reference for the structured data.... As in other PL is not permitted to define const pointers to data structures...

Comment: if you would like me to give you an example of this in another language so maybe you can understand it better. lets say JAVA, we have final ArrayList which can be assigned one time, but still you can change its children at any time.

Comment: the point here is that, the `const` pointing to reference to the object, which means that you cannot change or reassign the pointer to that object. That does not mean you cannot change the values of the content (elements or fields) in that object

Comment: in that terms It make sense... but still it's bit weird compared to other PL where const array = [] or const object= new Class() will normally produce a compiler syntax error.

Comment: I would like to remind you that TypeScript is built based on JavaScript and linting feature is not as powerful as the one in other languages. Linting here came to help reducing stress finding issues in the code rather than debugging it for long time. You can always define you own lint based on preference unlike other languages comes with set of pre-defined rules.

Comment: I see, but IMHO adding Lint checks on your code has a purpose to drive people to write (js) code following a more strict model. I think that a variable that points to a mutable value should definitely not be called or defined const(ant) as default

Comment: I can say they are trying to make it Type`Strict` to help developer to be careful dealing with their resources, that is why it is `const` by default. Otherwise you can disable linting on const if you wish too.

Comment: I would like to remind you if my answer solves the puzzle to select it the answer for this question. If not hopefully we can go through this.